# Bring OSX terminal to front after command finishes

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal, focus

I'm looking for a way for the terminal to get my attention after a command finishes. Something like this:

```
$ ./lengthy_command.sh ; focus_terminal
```

Is there any easy way to do that on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ ./lengthy_command.sh; osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate'
```

If you want to get even fancier:

```
$ ./lengthy_command.sh; osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'display alert "Done!"' -e 'end tell'
```

Comment: My god. That craziness actually works. :p

Comment: This AppleScript, open a new Terminal window, how can I just focus the existing Terminal window?

Comment: @user221797 These commands shouldn't open a new Terminal window unless there's no existing window to focus. Are you using some other terminal program instead of /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app? If so, you need to activate that one, instead of "Terminal".